# can a django application be run using paster?

Tags: python, django, pylons

can a django application be run using paster? Or is it pylons specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pylons specific.  There was a [Django Paste](http://pythonpaste.org/djangopaste/) project, but I'm not sure if it's active or how much progress was ever made.